# Генерация случайного числа по заданному распределению

Tags: python, математика, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей

Необходимо сгенерировать случайные числа `Х є [0, 1]`, которые распределены по такому закону:
[image: График функции распределения случайных чисел]

Comment: типа, нужно на нарисованной прямой генерить числа?

Comment: Это вероятности

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю задачу, в 2/3 случаев должны генерироваться числа `[0; 0.5)` и с уменьшающейся вероятностью - остальные `[0.5; 1)`.

Тогда можно сделать так

```
def generate():
  x = random.random() * 0.75
  return x if x < 0.5 else 1 - math.sqrt(3 - 4 * x) / 2
```

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist([generate() for _ in range(1000000)], bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Как вычислять

Для начала берем функцию вероятности из задания

```
def f(x):
    return 1 if x < 0.5 else -2*x + 2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Находим ее интеграл

```
def g(x):
    return x if x < 0.5 else -x**2 + 2*x - 0.25
```

Константу `c = -0.25` получаем из уравнения `-x**2 + 2*x + c = x при x = 0.5`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`g(x)` возвращает площадь заполненной части фигуры от `0` до `x`. Поэтому, если слово интеграл вызывает содрогание, реализовывать функцию нужно именно как вычисляющую площадь несложной геометрической фигуры.

Например `g(0.8)` вернет площадь следующей фигуры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А `g(0.6) - g(0.2)` – следующей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь реализуем функцию обратную к `g` - т.е. она будет принимать площадь, а возвращать `x`.

Для этого решаем квадратное уравнение `-x**2 + 2*x - 0.25 = y`

Получаем

```
def h(y):
    return y if y < 0.5 else 1 - math.sqrt(3 - 4 * y) / 2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь передавая в `h()` значения равномерно распределенные на отрезке `[g(0); g(1)]` будем получать значения распределенные на отрезке `[0; 1]` согласно нашей функции вероятностей.

т.е. `generate` можно переписать таким образом

```
def generate():
    return h(random.random() * (g(1) - g(0)) + g(0))
```

Comment: 1) В 1/2 случаев должны генерироваться числа [0; 0.5) и с уменьшающейся вероятностью - остальные [0.5; 1)
2) Почему 
                x = random.random() * 0.75

Comment: Для чисел >= 0.5 суммарная вероятность в два раза меньше чем для остальных (площадь треугольника в два раза меньше площади квадрата), поэтому получается именно 2/3

Comment: Объясните логику выражения, плз:
else 1 - math.sqrt(3 - 4 * x) / 2. Как оно выводится?

Comment: @GreyKoshak надеялся что до этого дело не дойдет. :) Обновил ответ

Comment: Все абсолютно понятно и интеграл не вызывает содроганий. Последнее уточнение: почему возникает С = -0.25, когда берется интеграл ф-ции y=-2*x + 2?

Comment: @GreyKoshak значит с вами приятно иметь дело :) я обновил ответ. в точке `x=0.5` значения функций `g1(x)=x` и `g2(x)=-x**2 + 2*x + c` должны совпадать, чтобы функция была непрерывной. Отсюда и получаем `c` приравнивая их